# Wrapping a method call in third party component with a bindable property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

Im a bit stuck as to the best approach for this. I have inhertited from a third party control so that I can create a property that I can bind to in my WPF MVVM application. I cannot bind to it because it is not a dependency property. If I was to implement as a dependency property I could call `RestoreLayout(value);` in the set but I would not get the value using `this.GetValue(LayoutXmlProperty);` in the get which feels wrong. Heres what I have which obviously doesnt work because I can't bind the LayoutXml property to of the control in my view to the relevant property in my view model.

```
public class WorkspaceLayoutControl : DockLayoutManager
{
    public string LayoutXml
    {
        get { return GetLayoutAsXml(); }
        set { RestoreLayout(value); }
    }

    private void RestoreLayout(string xml)
    {
        if (xml != String.Empty)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

            writer.Write(xml);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            RestoreLayoutFromStream(stream);
        }
    }

    private string GetLayoutAsXml()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        SaveLayoutToStream(stream);

        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could implement the dependency property as usual, and then call the `RestoreLayout` method from a property changed callback

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, you can register a `PropertyChangedCallback` for this exact purpose.  That way your getter and setter are strictly dealing with the dependency property wiring and the callback is handling the extra logic required.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LayoutXmlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "LayoutXml", typeof(string), typeof(WorkspaceLayoutControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(defaultValue,
                                  new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLayoutXmlChanged));

public string LayoutXml
{
    get { return (string) GetValue(LayoutXmlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LayoutXmlProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnLayoutXmlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var layoutControl = d as WorkspaceLayoutControl;
    if (layoutControl != null)
    {
        layoutControl.RestoreLayout(layoutControl.LayoutXml);
    }
}
```

MSDN article going into more depth here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That works for setting the value but doesn't quite work when you get the value. The link to the internal state of the control is broken.